# Mayan EDMS \n character showing in main menu

Tags: python, django, mayanedms

I am new to Django programming so I don't understand why is this happening. The problem is when I load the home page of the website in the first second everything loads fine like it should.

You can see at the picture below:
[image]

After that it loads a lot of \n characters without any reason, just in the main menu part in every new line under div `id="main-menu"`.
[image]
And here is a picture without background color:
[image]

I tried to search whole project for "\n" character to see if maybe some code is broken but everything looks fine. 
I also looked in django.po to see if it appeared in translations but nothing was wrong.

I don't know what am I missing.

[image]

Comment: For what version of Mayan is this? What browser are you using?